# is it fine to name django apps with capital letters?

Tags: sql, django, database, model

In django I named my app as "Home". I created a class named "images" inside models.py and make migrations thus I got table created in my database as "Home_images". but the problem arises when I tried to execute raw query on that table.

```
  query = "select * from Home_images" 
  cursor.execute(query)
```

string **query** gets converted into smaller letters so django couldn't find table named "Home_images". as it tries to find for table names "home_images", which is not present in database.

Comment: *"string query gets converted into smaller letters"* — Wut?

Comment: "select * from Home_images" get converted into "select * from home_images" as there is no table named "home_images" in database I got error.

Comment: Why do you think it gets converted and by what exactly?

Comment: @deceze  ` **ProgrammingError at /api/images/**
relation "home_image" does not exist
LINE 1:  select * from Home_image
                       ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/images/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value: 
relation "home_image" does not exist
LINE 1:  select * from Home_image
                       ^`

Comment: browser shows this error "home_image" does not exist and which is true, I have "Home_image" as table in database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unquoted PostgreSQL identifiers are case-insensitive and implicitly lowercased which is database standard and [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

so

```
select * from Home_images
```

is converted to

```
select * from home_images
```

by PostgreSQL

If you want case sensitive return you should quote  your name `"Home_images"`

Comment: In my opinion you should use snake case as this would be with Django standard ORM  generated naming scheme also leave queries to ORM and table generation to migrations

Comment: is it same for mysql or only applicable for postgresql ??

Comment: It is not hard to find it out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

It's Right but doesn't make queries like this in this condition your project will work file I also named my project app as 'KE' and it's working fine.